# not able to insert more than 200 docs with in mongodb using axios in nodojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to insert an array of **900 docs** in mongodb from an csv file. I was successful in reading the csv file and extracting 900 docs form it but I was enable to insert 900 docs at a time in mongodb using **insertMany()** . When I tries to insert 900 docs it refuses with no error. but when I use slice method **collection.slice(0,200)** to break the array upto 200 docs it successfully inserted.

My server side code-

```
    arrayToInsert = []
    const jsonArray = await csvtojson().fromFile(req.file.path);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
      var singleRow = {
        name: jsonArray[i]["name"],
        role: jsonArray[i]["role"],
      };
      arrayToInsert.push(singleRow);
    }
    console.log(arrayToInsert); // I am getting all 900 docs in console
    await salesData.insertMany(arrayToInsert) // It is not working
```

Working:

```
await salesData.insertMany(arrayToInsert.slice(0,200)) // It is working
```

**BUT why !!!**

Comment: "it refuses with no error"? Really? Absolutely nothing happens?

Comment: Nothing in MongoDB logs either?

Comment: did u add a try catch?

Comment: yes, It don't gives an error.
If I put respond in the success function of the insertMany() func. then 
It gives net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESE error for my api post req

Comment: and in mongodb console insertMany() is not logging until i uses slice method

Comment: I also used try and catch to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: yes , i am using mongoose